# "conda activate" fails on bash.exe even though works well on git-bash.exe

Tags: python, bash, shell, conda, git-bash

I want to use "conda activate" on bash.exe because I set it to VSCode default terminal. This is used when F5 debug runs.

System
- Windows 10
- Visual Studio Code 1.36.1
- conda 4.7.10
- Git for Windows v2.22.0

environment variables are set by Anaconda installation manager and `python` command works in any situations. However `conda activate` does not.
This command fails in a new bash.exe with the error below.

```
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
If using 'conda activate' from a batch script, change your
invocation to 'CALL conda.bat activate'.

To initialize your shell, run

    $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>

Currently supported shells are:
  - bash
  - cmd.exe
  - fish
  - tcsh
  - xonsh
  - zsh
  - powershell

See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.

IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'.
```

`conda activate` works well only in the following situations:
1. on git-bash.exe
2. opening bash.exe, and restarting shell by `exec $SHELL -l`, then `conda activate'

Regarding 1., why is there such a difference between git-bash.exe and bash.exe even though they are the same user and shell( `whoami`,`echo $SHELL` ) and perhaps refer to the same setting files( `/.bashrc` etc.)?

`conda activate` should complete in a new bash.exe.
What should I check?
Thank you.

Comment: "change your
invocation to 'CALL conda.bat activate'" : do what the message says because it's a windows cmd shell, not a unix-like shell.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. First, from the bash shell you must run:

```
conda init bash
```

It will add some command to `~\.bash_profile`,  but it looks like starting the terminal from VSCode does not run `.bash_profile`

Just move the added command below from `~\.bash_profile` to `~\.bashrc` and everything is working fine

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
eval "$('/c/Miniconda3/Scripts/conda.exe' 'shell.bash' 'hook')"
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```